# NameError: name 'is_vectorized_multidiscrete_observation' is not defined

Tags: python, environment, reinforcement-learning, nameerror

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from gym.envs.registration import register
from gym import spaces
import gym
import numpy as np
import gymnasium
import stable_baselines3

print(f"Stable-Baselines3 version: {stable_baselines3.__version__}")

class CustomEnv(gymnasium.Env):
    def __init__(self, dataset, columns):
        super(CustomEnv, self).__init__() 
        if dataset is None:
            raise ValueError("The dataset must be provided.")
        if columns is None:
            raise ValueError("The columns must be provided.")
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.columns = columns
        if not isinstance(dataset, pd.DataFrame):
            raise ValueError("The dataset must be a DataFrame.")
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.initial_balance = 10000.0  # Initial balance for trading
        self.current_step = 0  # Current step in the dataset
        self.balance = self.initial_balance
        self.holding = 0  # Number of units of the asset held by the agent
        # Use "MPN5P" as the price column
        self.price_column = "MPN5P"
        self.current_price = self.dataset[self.price_column].iloc[self.current_step]  # Current price of the asset
        self.action_space = gymnasium.spaces.discrete.Discrete(3)  
        self.observation_space = gymnasium.spaces.box.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)
        self.columns = columns

    def step(self, action):
        # Execute the action and update the environment state
        self._take_action(action)
        self.current_step += 1

        if self.current_step >= len(self.dataset):
           self.current_step = 0  # Reset if the end of the dataset is reached
           self.current_price = self.dataset[self.price_column].iloc[self.current_step]  # Update current price

        # Initialize reward with a default value
        reward = 0

        # Calculate reward based on the new state and the agent's action
        if self.current_step >= len(self.dataset):
            reward = self._compute_reward(action)

        # Initialize done and info outside the conditional block
        done = False  # For simplicity, assuming episodes never terminate
        info = {}  # Additional information (optional)
        truncated = False
        # Return observation, reward, done flag, and info dictionary
        return self._get_observation(), reward, done,truncated, info


    def reset(self, seed=None):
      # Reset the environment state
        self.current_step = 0
        self.balance = self.initial_balance
        self.holding = 0
        self.current_price = self.dataset[self.price_column].iloc[self.current_step]
        observation = np.array([self.current_price, self.initial_balance / self.initial_balance], dtype=np.float32)  # Ensure a NumPy array with shape (2,)
        info = {}  # Empty dictionary for info (if not used)
        print(f"Observation: {observation}")
        print(f"Info: {info}")  
        return observation, info  # Return both observation and reset info

    def _take_action(self, action):
        # Execute the action (buy, sell, or hold)
        if action == 0:  # Buy
            if self.balance >= self.current_price:
                self.holding += 1
                self.balance -= self.current_price
        elif action == 1:  # Sell
            if self.holding > 0:
                self.holding -= 1
                self.balance += self.current_price
    
    def _compute_reward(self, action):
        # Define reward computation (e.g., based on profit/loss)
        reward = 0
        if action == 0:  # Buy
            reward -= self.current_price
        elif action == 1:  # Sell
            reward += self.current_price
        return reward

    def _get_observation(self):
        current_price = self.dataset[self.price_column].iloc[self.current_step]
        normalized_balance = self.balance / self.initial_balance
        observation = np.array([current_price, normalized_balance], dtype=np.float32)
        return observation
```

This is my environment initialization code. I didn't use `MultiDiscrete` but out of somewhere I am getting `NameError`. I think it's from my `stable_baselines3` 2.2.1.
I installed `stable_baselines3` newer version but the code is only importing the older one for some reason.

I was expecting for the newer version to remove this glitch and train the RL model with PPO smoothly. I even edited `Dummy_vec_env.py` to expect a single environment instead of multiple as I am using vectorized environment.
I was thrown an error before to use vectorized environment which is why I used DummyVecEnv and then wrapped it.